# Difference between save and apply button?

Tags: save, joomla1.7, apply

i get confuse in apply and save button. whether Save will save the settings. Apply will save and apply the settings or apply will save the setting for instance or what?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a good explanation, it's for joomla 1.5 but it's the same principle:

http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/joomla-save-and-apply-buttons/

> - "Save" saves your changes and forces you out of the current screen
> - Apply" saves your changes but keeps you on the current screen